# React Router: How to redirect to a different component when a link/button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Just started learning web-dev recently so please excuse my perhaps naive question.

I've seen many examples of using `<Link>` and `<Route>` to update the page. However, most contain a fixed navigation bar where the links sit, and the components themselves have but static content.

It's not immediately clear to me as to how to correctly update the page if the links/buttons are inside the child component. For example, given a container:

```
<div id='container'><h1>components should be rendered in here, but only 1 at a time.</h1></div>
```

and 2 components, C1 and C2:

```
class C1 extends React.Component {
    /*other functions*/
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <p>Other things</p>
                <Button>Click me to Redirect to C2!</Button>
            </ div>
        )
    }
}

class C2 extends React.Component {
    /*other functions*/
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <p>Other things</p>
                <a>Click me to Redirect to C1!</a>
                <p>Other things</p>
            </ div>
        )
    }
}
```

Assume these 2 components are to be rendered under the 'container' div, with C1 being the default component.
How should I set up react-router to navigate between C1 & C2, and theoretically for more than two components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-router` and `react-router-dom` are two complementary libraries that help you use the Browser history api using [Javascript History package](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history) under the hood.

To implement what you want you should use [`BrowserRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter),  [`Switch`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch) and [`Route`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route) Components within `react-router-dom`. `BrowserRouter` acts as a provider to its children of some utilities and the current location the history is in (current hostname, pathname, queryParams, etc.) while `Switch` and `Route` work together by `Route` being the component that bind a path you want with a React component to render and `Switch` the component that checks between all its child `Route`'s and Render the first that match the current pathname the history has, you can add a `Route` without a `path` prop so `Switch` falls back to it in case the current history location doesn't match any.

An example Would be something like this

```
import React from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import C1 from './C1'
import C2 from './C2'

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return <div id="container">
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/view1" component={C1}/>
                    <Route path="/view2" component={C2}/>
                    <Route component={C1} />
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

Now, there's multiple ways to navigate through the declared pages. One is to directly use the [`Link` component](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link) and pass the pathname you want to go using the 'to' prop.

```
class C2 extends React.Component {
    /*other functions*/
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <p>Other things</p>
                <Link to="/view1">Click me to Redirect to C1!</Link>
                <p>Other things</p>
            </ div>
        )
    }
}
```

`Link` Actually renders an anchor with the `href` you gave through the `to` prop.

Another way to do navigate is to use the [history api](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history) which is injected as a prop when rendered from a Route. This allows you to add some more logic before actually setting the new location. Here's a simple example

```
class C2 extends React.Component {
    /*other functions*/
    redirectToC1(){
        // do some extra logic you may want
        this.props.history.push("/view1")
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <p>Other things</p>
                <a onClick={() => this.redirectToC1()}>Click me to Redirect to C1!</a>
                <p>Other things</p>
            </ div>
        )
    }
}
```

Be sure to dive in on the documentation to see more.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you! For some reason, I thought you must specify <BrowserRouter> in each component. As a result, the components were all anchored within each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the components as a functions, example :

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            isActive: true
        };
    }
    C1 = () => {
        return <h1>C1</h1>;
    };
    C2 = () => {
        return <h1>C2</h1>;
    };
    render() {
        return <div id="container">{this.state.isActive ? this.C1 : this.C2}</div>;
    }
}
```

with the example above not using any routers. you can see the documentation how to install and use react navigation here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation

Comment: So I suppose I need to pass around the child component's state right? For example C1.isActive or C2.isActive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scrollintoview
You can check out this small demo I made for reference [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-from-one-component-t2d7j?file=/src/App.js)

This [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59142256/react-hooks-passing-ref-to-child-to-use-scrollintoview) will also be useful

Comment: This is not exactly what I want to achieve, but it can still be useful later on. Thank you.